# How to convert a string "560,000" into an integer 560000 when importing from csv into database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

just started learning Rails and have managed to import a csv file into a database, but the price field in the csv has quotes and a comma like this: "560,000"

But if I make the price field as t.integer in the migration file, then add the data, the price gets imported as 560.  So, how do I remove the quotes and the comma before importing it? thanks, Adam

edit: here's the rake file:

```
require 'csv'    

task :csv_to_properties => [:environment] do 
  CSV.foreach("lib/assets/cbmb_sale.csv", :headers => true) do |row|

    Property.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example, assuming the price field is in `row` element 4:

```
CSV.foreach("lib/assets/cbmb_sale.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
  row[price=4].gsub!(/,/,'')
  Property.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

The `price=4` is just a handy way to document the index value of the price element, it creates a variable called price assigns the value 4 to it, then immediately uses it as the array index.

Since Property.create! is already taking care of the string to integer conversion, we can perform an in-place substitution for the regular expression that contains a comma `/,/` for an empty string `''`.

Comment: Definitely use this option if you you know the exact row that you need to convert.

Comment: thanks, the rake runs without an error and the data imports but the price is showing as 560

Comment: No wait it works!!! I forgot that the numbers start from 0 instead of 1 so I was trying to convert the next one in the row. Thanks so much guys, much appreciated, Adam

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Is there anything I need to change to earn a Correct Answer check mark?

Comment: ah I didn't see that I had to set the answer, sorry new here, I just checked it now, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
csvvalue = csvvalue.gsub!(/,/,'').to_i
```

Cheers!

Thanks for posting your code. I don't do a ton with converting csv's to hashes but something like this will probably work:

```
Property.create!(row.to_hash.each_pair{|k,v| row.store(k,v.gsub(/,/,'').to_i)})
```

Pretty ugly but probably pretty close to what you want.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I hate to sound dumb but where would I put that!? in the rake file I created to import the csv?

Comment: Hard to know exactly without seeing your code but yes, you would probably want it in your rake or wherever you were importing.

Comment: I added it to the rake file above but got the error message: undefined method `gsub!' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"220,000".scan(/\d+/).join().to_i
```